# Java input and filereader

Tags: java, input, filereader

I am trying to open up a file and add it to a textarea, but the textfile wont work not sure what exactly isnt working but i know that the compiler reaches the function/method where i implement the read in file code. Here is the code

```
public class PictureAndButton extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private JMenuItem menuOptionOne = new JMenuItem("Lägg till text", KeyEvent.VK_L);
private JTextField textFalt  = new JTextField();


public PictureAndButton()
{
menuInfo.add(menuOptionOne);
menuOptionOne.addActionListener(this);
textField.addActionListener(this);    
setSize(350, 150);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);       
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  if(e.getSource() == menuOptionOne)
    {
        readInFile(textField.getText());
    }
   }    

private void readInFile(String hej) 
{
   try
   {
       BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(hej));  
       while(true)
       {
           String rad = inFile.readLine();
          if(rad == null)
           break;
           textArea.append(rad);       

       }
   }
   catch(IOException e){}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PictureAndButton peanutButter = new PictureAndButton();
    }
```

}

I am running it on Eclipse and I am not getting any errors, the input text in the textfield doesnt change at all. Nothing is added to the text area. Really need some help on this

Comment: 1.) You have an infinite loop. 2.) You do not call readInFile() anywhere in your code.

Comment: Oh sorry. I inputted the wrong part of the code

Comment: A couple of advices; when you are giving a code example, it usually helps to name your variables to something that gives a clue about what they are, in English. For instance changing: rad -> line, hej -> file, "lägg till text" -> "add text" would help people understand what you are trying to do with a brief look and ultimately help you get useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to open up a file and add it to a textarea, ..

Use [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) instead.

e.g.

```
textArea.read(new FileReader(hej), hej);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some System.out.println(); to debug, like:

```
if(e.getSource() == menuOptionOne)
{
    System.out.println("Trying to load file: "+textField.getText());
    readInFile(textField.getText());
}
```

And more, use that try with and message inside the catch to know when something fails.

```
 try
 {
   BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(hej));  
   while(true)
   {
       String rad = inFile.readLine();
      if(rad == null)
       break;
       textArea.append(rad);       

   }
} catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("Problem on loading file .Because: "e.getMessage();
     }
```

Comment: The edits do not make it an answer.  It would make for a great comment.

Comment: @Claudiu C i received the message from the constructor, but nothing from the Exception..?

Comment: It says: Trying to load file: